# How can I determine if a directory is in use

Tags: windows-10, batch-file, files-folders

During a desktop application reinstall or update, I need to ensure the application's resources are not open or currently being used.

Using a batch file, I'm trying to determine if a directory is open via Windows Explorer or a command window. Is this possible, and if so how would I accomplish this?

Thank you in advance

Comment: I myself would use the system internals [handle application](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/handle).  You shouldn't be caring if it is open in command or explorer, you should be caring if there is an open handle to it.

Comment: I agree, use System Internals.  Or rename the directory and see if you get an error.  You have not shared which directory it is, so this may not be a viable option.

Comment: Did you mean something like this ? [Batch to open & restart Explorer.exe & then restore all the windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61635144/3080770)

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas It captured everything as I needed it to. Thank you

Comment: You are most welcome.

Answer (score 0):

With one line in Powershell, you can write something like that to get all Opened Folders :

---

***Powershell :***

```
@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder | ForEach { $_.Self.Path }
```

---

***Get Opened Folders with PowerShell code in a batch file :***

---

```bat
@ECHO off
@Title Get Opened Folders with PowerShell code in a batch file
Powershell -C "@((New-Object -com shell.application).Windows()).Document.Folder | ForEach { $_.Self.Path }"
pause
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, unfortunately, I was unable to get it to report those directories opened with the command shell.